# Mysql query to return regex match between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have two columns in a database I want to compare. One is email addresses and the other is username.

I'm looking to return results if the first part of username matches the first component of the email address (stuff before the @ sign).

Sample data:

> username emailaddress
>
> badzzycshulzey9802 badzzycshulzey@gmail.com
>
> trogleddg1919 trogleddg@gmail.com

Tried a variety of queries but I can't seem to get this one.... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a regexp for this, strings functions can do it:

```
select *
from mytable
where username like concat(substr(emailaddress, 1, locate('@', emailaddress) - 1), '%')
```

`locate('@', emailaddress)` gives you the position of the arobas in the email address, and `substr(emailaddress, 1, locate(...) - 1)` extracts everything before that. Then, we can check if the `username` starts with that part of the email address using `like` with a wildcard on the right side.